# PrintWindow() WebBrowser returns a black image

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm making an application which would open flash game in WebBrowser and scan for pixels, so I'm trying to capture an image which I would scan after. This application would run in background (not minimized) so I cannot use standard screenshot capture, that is why I used PrintWindow function which captures certain area. I got MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX HWND using EnumWindows and tried to print it's region. Although code below is from Delphi, I used the same PrintWindow on C# and I got black image too, so it is something to do with PrintWindow function. Tried webBrowser.DrawToBitmap too - still black image...

```
function PrintWindow(HWND:HWND;hdcBlt:HDC;nFlags:DWORD):BOOL; stdcall; external 'user32.dll'

function zPrintWindow(hHWND: HWND; Bmp: TBitmap): Boolean;
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  result := False;
  GetWindowRect(hHWND, r) ;
  bmp.Width := r.Right - r.Left;
  bmp.Height := r.Bottom - r.Top;
  bmp.PixelFormat:=pf24bit;
  result := PrintWindow(hHWND, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0) ;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  zPrintWindow(StrToInt(Edit1.Text), Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
  Image1.Refresh;
end;
```

The game I'm trying to capture screens is Wartune, but when captured, it gives black images. When tried other games, I get correct image. I also captured full form with various methods, including PrintWindow, but still - WebBrowser was in black. Why is this happening? Could it be because the game is high definition?

Here is picture of black screen with PrintWindow. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8569.jpg
Here is picture how should it look (Captured with Alt+PrintScreen). https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtclU.jpg
Here is picture of other game which is captured okay with PrintWindow. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7luSZ.jpg

Comment: @moskito-x The thing is that the application will run in background, that means a lot of other windows will be in front. Your given example takes screenshots of visible part.

Comment: okay I delete my comment

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MSIE is installed on your machine? If you are using 9.0 beta, it might have issue, because it uses hardware acceleration interface D2D/DWrite to render pages.

But I highly doubt that the window handle you passed into the function, is not the window that renders contents. Usually I capture webpage content by using the following code.

```
function TWebBrowserDescent.GetThumbnail: TBitmap;
var
  VOPtr: IViewObject;
  R: TRect;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  if Supports(Document, IViewObject, VOPtr) then
  begin
    Result.Width  := ClientWidth;
    Result.Height := ClientHeight;
    R := Result.Canvas.ClipRect;
    try
      VOPtr.Draw(DVASPECT_DOCPRINT, 0, nil, nil, 0, Result.Canvas.Handle, @R, nil, nil, 0);
    except
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Using the code, you can capture the visible part (viewport) of the browser. It should be able to capture embedded ActiveX controls. As the next step, you might scroll the browser to particular position, in order to make the whole Flash visible.

**If other web pages work with the code but only your problematic page does work with it, I think the ActiveX control does not implement** `IViewObject` **interface.**

I hope the answer can help you.